# Elliptic-type integral with parameters: Maximum

Tags: elliptic-integrals, implicit-function

I am stuck with the integral
$$ I(\epsilon,\lambda)=\frac1\epsilon\int\limits_0^{\frac\pi2} \frac{1+\left(\lambda\epsilon^4-1\right)\cos^2\phi}{\sqrt{1+\left(\epsilon^4-1\right)\cos^2\phi\,}} \,\text{d}\phi \,.
$$
***Note**: In a first version, I unfortunately forgot the square root in the denominator.*

Here, $0<\epsilon\leq1$ and $\lambda\geq 1$ are (real) parameters. Wolfram Alpha gives me the solution (if I didn't mistype something)
$$ \frac{\epsilon^5}{\epsilon^4-1}\left[ \left(1-\lambda\right)K\!\left(1-\frac{1}{\epsilon^4}\right) + \left(\lambda\epsilon^4 -1\right)E\!\left(1-\frac{1}{\epsilon^4}\right)\right]$$
with elliptic integral of first and second kind. However, I have little experience with those, and I can't seem to get gnuplot to plot the result. (Possibly related to the conventions for the parameters of ellitic integral, $m$ vs $k^2$?)

Anyway, I don't particularly need specific values (which are presumably not expressible as elementary functions), but rather, I'm interested in the extrema of $I(\epsilon,\lambda)$:

1. Specifically, I would like to find the extremum of $I(\epsilon,\lambda)$ as a function of $\epsilon$ with $\lambda$ treated as a parameter (i.e. the $\epsilon$ for which $\partial/\partial \epsilon \,I(\epsilon,\lambda)=0$).
2. I have the hunch that for $\lambda=1$, the extremum should be at $\epsilon=1$ and it should be a minimum (by symmetry of the underlying problem). However, even that eludes me right now.

How can I make progress here?

Comment: I obtained the asymptotics of $\epsilon_*$ as functions of $\lambda$. See my edit.

Comment: Updated and improved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have found is that
$$I(\epsilon,\lambda)=\frac{\left(\lambda  \epsilon ^4-1\right) E\left(1-\epsilon ^4\right)-(\lambda
   -1) \epsilon ^4 K\left(1-\epsilon ^4\right)}{\epsilon  \left(\epsilon
   ^4-1\right)}$$

The partial derivative is

$$\epsilon ^2
   \left(\epsilon ^4-1\right)^2\frac{\partial{I(\epsilon,\lambda)} }{\partial\epsilon}=$$ $$\epsilon ^4 K\left(1-\epsilon ^4\right) \left(3 \lambda +(\lambda -3)
   \epsilon ^4-1\right)+$$ $$\left(\epsilon ^4 \left(\lambda  \left(\epsilon
   ^4-5\right)+5\right)-1\right) E\left(1-\epsilon ^4\right)$$

So, for the minimum value of $I(\epsilon,\lambda)$ we need to find for $\epsilon$ the zero of
$$F(\epsilon)=\epsilon ^4 K\left(1-\epsilon ^4\right) \left(3 \lambda +(\lambda -3)
   \epsilon ^4-1\right)+$$ $$\left(\epsilon ^4 \left(\lambda  \left(\epsilon
   ^4-5\right)+5\right)-1\right) E\left(1-\epsilon ^4\right)$$ which does not show explicit solutions.

However, for small values of $\epsilon$, an expansion gives
$$F(\epsilon)=-1+\epsilon ^4 \left(\lambda  (6\log (2)-5)+3(1-2 \lambda ) \log (\epsilon
   )+\frac{21}{4}-3\log (2)\right)+\frac{3}{64} \epsilon ^8 (32 \lambda -8 (4
   \lambda +5) \log (2)+8 (4 \lambda +5) \log (\epsilon )-17)+O\left(\epsilon
   ^{12}\right)$$
Neglecting the second terms and letting $\epsilon^4=t$, this reduces to an equation which can be solved in terms of Lambert function and then an *under estimate*

$$\epsilon_* =\sqrt[4]{-\frac{4}{3 (2 \lambda -1) W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{12 (2\lambda -1)}e^{\frac{20 \lambda-21 }{3(2 \lambda-1)   }}\right)}}$$ which will be better and better when $\lambda$ increases.

Using $\epsilon_*$ as the starting point of Newton method for solving $F(\epsilon_*)=0$, by Darboux theorem, we should face one overshoot of the solution as soon as $\lambda >4$.

Now, it is probably time for some calculations
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\lambda & \epsilon_* & I_{\text{min}} & \epsilon_{\text{min}} \\
 1.0 & 0.747537 & 1.57080& 1.000000 \\
 1.5 & 0.707936 & 1.90443& 0.818125 \\
 2.0 & 0.662338 & 2.15824& 0.713646 \\
 2.5 & 0.618508 & 2.36458& 0.645006 \\
 3.0 & 0.580530 & 2.53956& 0.595829 \\
 3.5 & 0.548739 & 2.69225& 0.558447 \\
 4.0 & 0.522167 & 2.82824& 0.528801 \\
 4.5 & 0.499737 & 2.95121& 0.504535 \\
 5.0 & 0.480557 & 3.06372& 0.484183 \\
 5.5 & 0.463945 & 3.16765& 0.466783 \\
 6.0 & 0.449389 & 3.26436& 0.451672 \\
 6.5 & 0.436501 & 3.35494& 0.438381 \\
 7.0 & 0.424986 & 3.44022& 0.426562 \\
 7.5 & 0.414615 & 3.52087& 0.415958 \\
 8.0 & 0.405208 & 3.59745& 0.406368 \\
 8.5 & 0.396623 & 3.67040& 0.397636 \\
 9.0 & 0.388744 & 3.74010& 0.389637 \\
 9.5 & 0.381477 & 3.80688& 0.382272 \\
 10.0 & 0.374746 & 3.87101& 0.375458
\end{array}
\right)$$

You could easily make some empirical curve fit of the exact values of $\epsilon$ for generating better estimates for the iterative methods.
$$\epsilon_0=1-\frac{0.457127 (\lambda-1)}{1+0.628628 (\lambda-1)}$$ could be a good starting point (at least for $1 \leq \lambda \leq 10$ - for which $R^2=0.999948$) .

Even with the poor estimate $\epsilon_0$ when $\lambda$ is small, using Newton, Halley or Householder methods does not make any problem. For example, for $\lambda=2$, the iterates are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 n & \text{Newton} & \text{Halley} & \text{Householder} \\
 0 & 0.662338 & 0.662338 & 0.662338 \\
 1 & 0.708735 & 0.712290 & 0.713415 \\
 2 & 0.713573 & 0.713645 & 0.713646 \\
 3 & 0.713645 & 0.713646 &  \\
 4 & 0.713646 &  & 
\end{array}
\right)$$

It seems that something as simple as
$$\epsilon_* \sim  \frac{0.415681 \lambda+2.10534}{1.54228 \lambda+1}\qquad \qquad (R^2=0.999957)$$ will allow a very fast convergence of Newton method.

Comment: Thank you -- however, I unfortunately forgot an important square root in the question...

Comment: Thank you again, but I'm looking for $\epsilon_*$ for given $\lambda$ (which seems to be much harder).

Comment: @Toffomat. Have a look at my edit.

Comment: Wow, great! (Which program did you use?)

Comment: @Toffomat. Mathematica for a big part and things of my own for the solutions (Mma does it very easily). Cheers :-)

Comment: OK, impressive!